# Clicking the new_photo_path link redirects to login_path .. how do I get back there after?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:new, :create] 
end

class ApplicationController
  def logged_in_user
    unless logged_in?
      store_location
      flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
      redirect_to login_url
    end
  end
end

module SessionHelper 
  def store_location 
   session[:forwarding_url] = request.url if request.get?
  end

  def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(session[:forwarding_url] || default)
    session.delete(:forwarding_url)
  end
end

class SessionsController 
  def new
    ...
    redirect_back_or(default)
  end
end
```

Before we can visit `example.com/photos/new` we must login.

However, after logging in, it is redirecting me back to the `login_path`. I want to be redirected_to `new_photo_path` instead.

Why is `request.url` not `example.com/photos/new`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SessionsController` had an error:

`redirect_back_or(default)` should be `redirect_back_or user`